# How to stop reconnecting previous socket object in kotlin?

Tags: sockets, kotlin, socket.io, io

I am currently working on a chat app android project and I am experiencing a bug. The bug I've found is that when I open the app, the socket connects successfully but when I exit the app and open again, the previous socket will create a connection. It reconnects. I already added IO.Options forceNew to true but it didn't work. Below is my code snippet on how I connect to the server

```
val opts = IO.Options()
        opts.forceNew = true
        opts.reconnection = false
        socket = IO.socket("https://test.com.ph:3000",opts)
        socket.connect()
        socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT) {
            activity.runOnUiThread {
                Timber.d("$MESSAGING_URL ==========> CONNECTED")
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried socket.close() when exiting the app?

Comment: Yes. I already tried that @Y.Kakdas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I figure out that when the app was closed by using the back button, it will not totally kill the app. It was added on the background thread. And when I open the app again, it will create another thread resulting to multiple socket listening. So what I did was I kill the app totally when onDestroy was called like this:

```
override fun onDestroy() {
   super.onDestroy()
   android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid())
}
```